# How do I resolve an IPC error in Open VMS web service integration toolkit (WSIT)

Tags: ipc, openvms, vms, wsit

I have inherited a 'technology' stack that I have very little experience of and am hoping for help to resolve an issue.  Using the OpenVMS Web Service Integration Toolkit to call OpenVMS service from a web browser I am receiving the following error:

'com.hp.wsi.WsiConnectionException: ERROR: Transceive failure EndPointLocate: %WSI-F-FAILED_IPC_INIT, Unexpected failure while initializing IPC context'

Switching on IPC debugging shows the following:

```
 (wsi$$protocol_init) Initialized (once only), OK
 (wsi$$protocol_list_new) OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_THREADS=1, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_STACKSIZE=2000000, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_INIT_F=0x00080328, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_TRANSCEIVE_F=0x00080348, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_DISCONNECT_F=0x00080368, OK
 (wsi$$error_set) iError=0x0001004a (65610) (IPC,ERROR,9)
 (wsi$$error_set) osError=0x0000045c (1116)
 (wsi$$error_set) "I/O failure: SYS$ICC_OPEN_ASSOC() failed"
 (_icc_init_assoc_locked) sys$icc_open_assoc(ICC$PID_00003E97_WSI) failed, st=1116
```

A successful connection shows:

```
 (wsi$$protocol_init) Initialized (once only), OK
 (wsi$$protocol_list_new) OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_THREADS=1, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_STACKSIZE=2000000, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_INIT_F=0x00080328, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_TRANSCEIVE_F=0x00080348, OK
 (_set_srv_context) pctx=0x00f617f8, WSI$_SRV_DISCONNECT_F=0x00080368, OK
 (_icc_init_assoc_locked) sys$icc_open_assoc(ICC$PID_000071BF_WSI), assoc=0x00010001, OK
 (wsi$$protocol_binding_compose_d) ProtSeq="wsi_icc"
 (wsi$$protocol_binding_compose_d) NetAddr="SVF"
 (wsi$$protocol_binding_compose_d) EndPoint="ICC$PID_000071BF_WSI"
```

I am guessing this is a resourcing issue but have no idea what needs to be changed.

Any help very much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting `SS$_SSFAIL (1116)` error from [`sys$icc_open_assoc`](http://h30266.www3.hpe.com/odl/axpos/opsys/vmsos84/4527/4527pro_072.html#index_x_706), that is from ICC (Intra-cluster communication) servces:

```
SS$_SSFAIL  Transport association name table is full, systemwide.
```

Perhaps, some process does not exit cleanly, thus the resources are not released.

Quoting from the doc:

> `SYS$ICC_OPEN_ASSOC`
>
> ...
>    The association name space is a controlled resource. For information about managing this resource, see the *HP OpenVMS System Manager's Manual*.
>
> An attempt to open an association with a name not authorized as described in the *HP OpenVMS System Manager's Manual* will fail with the error SS$_NOPRIV returned to the caller. In addition to making entries in the system's local association name space, a call to $ICC_OPEN_ASSOC may also make an entry in a simple clusterwide registry of active associations.
>
> An association may only be accessed from the mode in which it was opened. Inner modes are prevented from using the default association.
>
> An application can open any number of associations subject to available process BYTLM quota. Currently, there is a systemwide limit of 512 open associations. There is no limit imposed clusterwide.

Comment: Thank you for you help gustogusto - very much appreciated.  As part of on going investigation I have increased several quotas the last one being the BYTLM quota which I increased from 4000000 to 6000000.  This has helped reduce the occurrences of the issue but not stopped it altogether.  I will continue increasing the quote as see if it fixes the problem. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Gustogusto was spot on - there is a OpenVMS system-wide limit on the number of associations permitted and the error 0x0000045c is thrown when the limit of 512 associations (connections) is reached (see details below). At this time there is no fix for this issue.  A possible workaround could be to configure this machine into a cluster, since there’s no limit on associations in a cluster-wide setup. Another possible workaround may be to periodically stop/restart the WSIT Software.

The IPC logs highlight that the SYS$ICC_OPEN_ASSOC() call fails with error 0x0000045c.

The SYS$ICC_OPEN_ASSOC() opens an "association"  with the Intra-Cluster Communications, so that it can receive incoming connections.

There’s a way to verify this limit is through SDA. The commands:

$ analyze/system
SDA> ICC SHOW ASSOCIATIONS will display all open ICC associations.

Example Output:

ICC Associations

```
            --- ICCPAB Summary Page ---

ICCPAB Addr   Extended Process name     State  Conn Association Name
-----------  ---PID--- --------------- ------- ---- ----------------
 896771C0     00000433 WSI$MANAGER     Open       0 WSI$MANAGER_REPTAR
 896AB440     00000442 MATH_0442       Open       0 ICC$PID_00000442
 896AA2C0     00000442 MATH_0442       Open       0 ICC$PID_00000442_WSI
 896B1080     00000443 STOCK_0443      Open       0 ICC$PID_00000443
 896AA140     00000443 STOCK_0443      Open       0 ICC$PID_00000443_WSI
```

I then created this COM file to alert when limit is being approached to allow garbage collections to clear orphaned processes:

```
$ SET NOON
$ SET NOVERIFY
$ SUBMIT/QUE='<batch que name here>'/AFTER="+00:10"/LOG=ICC.LOG ICC.COM
$ ANALYSE/SYSTEM
SET OUTPUT/SINGLE HPESUPPORT-ICC.TXT
ICC SHOW ASSOCIATIONS
EXIT
$ pipe sear HPESUPPORT-ICC.TXT "ws1_","open"/mat=and/stats/out=ICC.TXT|search sy
s$input "records matched"/out=t.t
$ OPEN/READ INFILE T.T
$ READ/END_OF_FILE=EOF INFILE Temp
$ CLOSE INFILE
$ TEMP = F$EXTRACT(30, 3, TEMP)
$ IF TEMP .GE. 500
$ THEN
$    mail/subject="ICC limit alert" ICC.TXT "email address here"
$ ENDIF
$ EOF:
$ PURGE/KEEP = 144 icc.log
$ PURGE/KEEP = 144 hpesupport-icc.txt
$ PURGE/KEEP = 144 t.t
$ !+
$ ! Show connection count chronologically.
$ !-
$ !type t.t;*/out=p.t
$ !sort/key=(pos:30,siz=3) p.t sys$output
$ !+
$ ! List connections in user name sequence.
$ !-
$ !sear hpesupport-icc.txt "Process Name:     WS1_"/format=dump/out=p.t
$ !sort/key=(pos:42,siz=12) P.t sys$output
$ EXIT
```

Now off to find out why processes are being orphaned as this will prevent the limit being reached quite so quickly.